# Why isn't Elasticsearch detecting my custom made analyzer?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, analyzer

I made an index "user-name" with a custom made analyzer called 'autocomplete':

```
client.indices.create({
    index: 'user-name',
    type: 'text',
    settings: {
      analysis: {
        filter: {
          autocomplete_filter: {
            type: 'edge-ngram',
            min_gram: 1,
            max_gram: 20
          }
        },
        analyzer: {
          autocomplete: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: [
              'lowercase',
              'autocomplete_filter'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I try to reference this custom made analyzer by trying to use it in a mapping:

```
    client.indices.putMapping({
        index: 'user-name',
        type: 'text',
        body: {
          properties: {
            name: {
              type: 'string',
              analyzer: 'autocomplete',
              search_analyzer: 'standard'
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

but then I get this error: "reason": "analyzer [autocomplete] not found for field [name]". Why isn't my autocomplete analyzer being detected? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You simply need to put the index `settings` inside the `body` parameter:

```
client.indices.create({
    index: 'user-name',
    type: 'text',
    body: {
     settings: {
      analysis: {
        filter: {
          autocomplete_filter: {
            type: 'edge-ngram',
            min_gram: 1,
            max_gram: 20
          }
        },
        analyzer: {
          autocomplete: {
            type: 'custom',
            tokenizer: 'standard',
            filter: [
              'lowercase',
              'autocomplete_filter'
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: type: 'text', is not supported anymore, remove that line, and also instead of type: 'edge-ngram', use type: 'edge_ngram' as of August 2020

Comment: @AleksandarT yeah, obviously things have evolved since 2016.