# How to put additional settings when index in aws elasticsearch using node.js

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, aws-sdk, aws-elasticsearch

I'm gonna put additional settings details into client.index function.
Here's what I tried.

```
return client
    .index({
      index: indexName,
      type: "file",
      id: bucketName + "/" + fileKey,
      body: {
        title: fileName,
        content: contentString,
        fileKey: fileKey,
        bucketName: bucketName,
        updated: Date.now(),
        type: fileType,
      },
    })
```

How can I put analysis details into this?
This is what I'm gonna put.

```
{
   settings: {
      analysis: {
         analyze: {
             tokenizer: "icu-tokenizer"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Finally it should look like this:

```
{
    "ghej": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {},
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "ghej",
                "creation_date": "1592239308694",
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "content": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "1yX6z-eARdyNakJwM6Z3ow",
                "version": {
                    "created": "7010199"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**The `"settings"` property needs to be inside the `"body"` property.**

**In the body you need to define analyzer/tokenizer parameters and the text on which the analysis should be performed**

You can refer this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html)

```
returnclient.index({
  index: indexName,
  type: "file",
  id: bucketName+"/"+fileKey,
  body: {
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_icu_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

})
```

You can refer these blogs and answer to know more

[Elasticsearch Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454956/elasticsearch-analyzer-lowercase-and-whitespace-tokenizer)

[Custom Made Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159972/why-isnt-elasticsearch-detecting-my-custom-made-analyzer)

[Integrate Elasticsearch with Node.js](https://qbox.io/blog/integrating-elasticsearch-into-node-js-application)

Comment: @U_M did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you and if it's helpful, please dont forget to upvote and accept :)